# Storing data from file in form of a dictionary (+pandas possibly)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, for-loop

I have a file which spits out some data every 100 time-steps, for 100000 time-steps. So, in total I have 1000 sets of data points. I would like to plot all of these onto 1 graph, with the key as the time-step. And ultimately, I would like to finally plot an average of all these data points.

A simplified example of what my data looks like:

```
#Timestep  
0   p 
a   b   c   d 
e   f   g   h 
100 p 
a   b   c   d
e   f   g   h
```

And what I want is: `{0: [[b, f], [c, g]], 100: [[b, f], [c, g]]}` 
Where `[b, f]` are my x values, and `[c, g]` are my y values.

My starting position:

```
with open('rdf.test', 'r') as f:
    d = {}

    x, y = [], []
    l = [x, y]
    for i in f:
        if i.startswith('#'):
            continue
        i = i.split()
        #if len(i) ==2:
```

I honestly currently have no idea how to go about doing this and would really appreciate if anyone can nudge me in the right direction.

Thank you, 
Kind regards, 
A confused student.

Comment: So you want to plot the timesteps on the x axis, and the average of datapoints on the y axis? Are the datapoints actually letters? In which case do you want to plot the frequency counts of letters? What is a .test file extension? Did you mean .txt?

Comment: Have you looked at the python documentation? e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: @Vash   - **1.**  For each time step, 50 x and y values are given, and it gives a header `0        50` to show that its timestep 0, and will out put 50 data points. What im trying to do is, each time I get a header, I would like to store the 50 x and y values in a dictionary with a key for those values.  **2.** No, the data points are actually letter, i simply wrote that for simplicity. **3.** The file extension is arbitrary, either way, my data is given as _rdf.dist_.

Comment: @Vash *  2. No, the data points aren't actually letter